# xml rpc response map to object C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have the following

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <struct>
               <member>
                  <name>1</name>
                  <value>
                     <struct>
                        <member>
                           <name>imageID</name>
                           <value>
                              <string>40087</string>
                           </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                           <name>imageURL</name>
                           <value>                         <string>http://local.server.gr/public_html/main/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?id=40087</string>
                           </value>
                        </member>
                     </struct>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>2</name>
                  <value>
                     <struct>
                        <member>
                           <name>imageID</name>
                           <value>
                              <string>40088</string>
                           </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                           <name>imageURL</name>
                           <value>
                              <string>http://local.server.gr/public_html/main/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?id=40088</string>
                           </value>
                        </member>
                     </struct>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>3</name>
                  <value>
                     <struct>
                        <member>
                           <name>imageID</name>
                           <value>
                              <string>40089</string>
                           </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                           <name>imageURL</name>
                           <value>
                              <string>http://local.server.gr/public_html/main/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?id=40089</string>
                           </value>
                        </member>
                     </struct>
                  </value>
               </member>
            </struct>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodResponse>`
```

xmlrpc response from a server.

I have tried different types of objects that accept and successfully serialize this xml but not with success. I cannot understand the "name" element that changes integer values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cant get from ur description - you need to serialize or deserialize to c# objects?

Comment: XML-RPC was superseded by SOAP before even the first version of .NET came out in 2002. Essentially it's a set of key/value pairs  (actually name/value pairs) similar to Json. If you can't persuade the people that create the server to use something more ... fresh, you should look for a library like [XML-RPC.Net](http://xml-rpc.net/), also available as a Nuget package

Comment: @Mitklantekutli the question is clear - the OP wants to deserialze the server's response. That's not immediatelly because the *elements* have different content and structure, just like Json.

Comment: What server are you trying to call? Does it have a Json API you can use instead of XML-RPC ? Are you trying to work with a site that uses Frontpage extensions perhaps?

Comment: Just to clarify, i get this xml as response from a server and i want to deserialize this response into an object. No, the server has no json api, just xml rpc. I have an class interface that implements IXmlRpcProxy, and there i have all the webmethods i can call. For this function the result is a bit more complex than just an integer or string. So I havent figured out the compatible object - return type i should have.

Answer (score 1):

XML-RPC was created by Microsoft and superseded by SOAP before the first .NET version in 2002. The trouble with it is that you have no idea what the actual objects' schema is. XML-RPC is similar to Json, it serializes everything as name/value items that could be used to reconstruct an object's properties. You have no idea though what all those properties are.

What you *can* do, is deserialize the elements so that you can read them at least. Luckily, XML-RPC was used by Frontpage and its usage survived with SharePoint. This means there is a ready-made schema you can use [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797558(v=office.12).aspx).

You can generate C# classes from it using the old `xsd.exe` program. Save the schema to a file (eg xmlrpc.xsd), ensure there are no whitespaces before the  tag and use the following line to generate the classes :

```
xsd xmlrpc.xsd /c /nx:XlmRpcNS
```

where `XmlRpcNS` is the namespace you want to use for the generated classes. Add the generated file to your project (by default it's `xmlrpc.cs`) and use them to deserialize the response, eg:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(response))
{
    var sz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(methodResponse));
    var methodResponse= (methodResponse)sz.Deserialize(reader);
    var content = (methodResponseParams)methodResponse.Item;
    var structContent = (StructType)content.param.value.Item;
    //...
}
```

The problem is that `xsd.exe` generates an `object Item` property for each choice element, which is why you need to cast to the proper type.

Another option is to use `dynamic` to avoid the casts. You lose Intellisens this way though:

```
dynamic methodResponse= (methodResponse)sz.Deserialize(reader);
var members = methodResponse.Item.param.value.Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq.  Works real nice in this case

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication33
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("struct").FirstOrDefault().Elements("member").Select(x => new {
                name = (int)x.Element("name"),
                imageID = x.Descendants("member").Where(y => (string)y.Element("name") == "imageID").Select(z => (int)z.Descendants("string").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),
                imageURL = x.Descendants("member").Where(y => (string)y.Element("name") == "imageURL").Select(z => (string)z.Descendants("string").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),

            }).ToList();
        }
    }


}
```

---

Into a class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication33
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Image.images = doc.Descendants("struct").FirstOrDefault().Elements("member").Select(x => new Image() {
                name = (int)x.Element("name"),
                imageID = x.Descendants("member").Where(y => (string)y.Element("name") == "imageID").Select(z => (int)z.Descendants("string").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),
                url = x.Descendants("member").Where(y => (string)y.Element("name") == "imageURL").Select(z => (string)z.Descendants("string").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),

            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Image
    {
        public static List<Image> images { get; set; }
        public int name { get; set; }
        public int imageID { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After considering your answers, the dynamic keyword make me think of this solution that is not perfect but does its work.
I make return type of the method dynamic and then analyse with the visual studio debugger the dynamic object at run time. Then i construct this class:

```
public class ImageListResult
{
    public List<ImageSlot> Slots { get; set; }
    public ImageListResult(dynamic res)
    {
        this.Slots = new List<ImageSlot>();
        try {
            int keys = res.Keys.Count;
            int values = res.Values.Count;

            if (keys == values)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++)
                {
                    ImageSlot slot = new ImageSlot()
                    {
                        Index = int.Parse(res.Keys[i])
                    };

                    int subCount = res.Values[i].Keys.Count;
                    for (int j = 0; j < subCount; j++)
                    {
                        string k = res.Values[i].Keys[j];
                        string v = res.Values[i].Values[j];
                        if (k.ToLower().Trim() == "imageid")
                        {
                            slot.ImageId = v;
                        }
                        else if(k.ToLower().Trim() == "imageurl")
                        {
                            slot.ImageUrl = v;
                        }
                    }

                    this.Slots.Add(slot);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public class ImageSlot
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// το index του image slot, απο το 1 εως το 25
        /// </summary>
        public int Index { get; set; } 

        public string ImageId { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }

}
```

so i successfully managed to deserialize the response. Its not ideal but its OK. If anyone think of a better solution feel free to post it, thanks for your answers

Comment: Did you try XML-RPC.NET ? Or check for an *alternative* API? Eg SharePoint has SOAP and REST APIs that provide the same functionality as XML-RPC.

Comment: I use CookComputing.XmlRpcV2 library. Only XML-RPC i can use in this case. thanks

Comment: Did you try my solution which is a lot less code, doesn't use a 2nd party dll, and gives same results?

Comment: i check your solution. But, i have already implement the largest part with this library and so far have very few code lines for the xml part.